# Record Posted Twice While Retrieving LAST_INSERT_ID Value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I implemented code in asp.net for storing record and retrieving identity field value. here is my code.

```
str.Append("Insert Into Table1(value1,value2)values(?value1,?value2);Select LAST_INSERT_ID();");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str.ToString(), con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?value1", value1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?value2", value2));
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
  con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long id = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

When i check my database, each record posted twice. when i remove line.

```
 long id = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Every thing fine, but not identity retrieved.
How can i implement code in order to retrieve identity field value and record posted one time only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` executes the query and returns the result. `ExecuteNonQuery` executes the query. That means you are executing the query twice here by calling both. Get rid of the `ExecuteNonQuery` method and you will be good

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
   con.Open();    

long id = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```